# How to include the outer class in the exception message?

Tags: python, exception, inner-classes

I would like to get a more accurate exception message when using an inner class as exception. For example:

```
import csv

class CsvReader: # pylint: disable=too-few-public-methods
    """ Handles reading of the CSV input file
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.file_name = 'test.csv'
        self.header = ''

    def read_file(self):
        """ Reads the CSV file.
        """
        with open(self.file_name) as csvfile:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            line_count = 0
            for row in csv_reader:
                if len(row) == 0:
                    continue
                if len(row) != 5:
                    raise self.BadRowFormat(row, line_count)
                if line_count == 0:
                    self.header = row.copy() # clone the list
                line_count += 1
            print(f'Processed {line_count} lines.')

    class BadRowFormat(Exception):
        """ Exception thrown when a line of the CSV file does not satisfy the
        expected format
        """
        def __init__(self, row, line_count):
            super().__init__(f'Could not parse line {line_count}: {", ".join(row)}. '
                             f'Expected 5 fields, got {len(row)}')

def main():
    """ Main function
    """
    csv_reader = CsvReader()
    csv_reader.read_file()


main()
```

and the input file `test.csv`:

```
Name,Places,Adult price,Pensioner price,Children price
B1,50,100,60,50
B2,100,120,70,60
B3,150,125,75,60
1
```

When I run this script I get the following exception message:

```
 File "./t.py", line 43, in <module>
    main()
  File "./t.py", line 40, in main
    csv_reader.read_file()
  File "./t.py", line 22, in read_file
    raise self.BadRowFormat(row, line_count)
__main__.BadRowFormat: Could not parse line 4: 1. Expected 5 fields, got 1
```

Is it possible to get a more descriptive exception message than: `__main__.BadRowFormat`? I would like to have something like `CsvReader.BadRowFormat` or `__main__.CsvReader.BadRowFormat` that will show the user that exception originated from the `CsvReader` class.

Comment: The exception message is the "Could not parse..." string you're defining in the constructor; this should have a reference to your `CsvReader` class if that's something you want to show the user.  Defining the exception class inside another class does not automatically modify either its name or its exception message.

Comment: Personally I'd define this exception outside of `CsvReader` and call it `CsvReaderParseError` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this construction:

```
class BadRowFormat(Exception):
        """ Exception thrown when a line of the CSV file does not satisfy the
        expected format
        """
        def __init__(self, classname, row, line_count):
            super().__init__(f'{classname}: Could not parse line {line_count}: {", ".join(row)}. '
                             f'Expected 5 fields, got {len(row)}')
```

And then call it with:

```
self.BadRowFormat(self.__class__.__name__, row, line_count)
```

This way you can add the class name in the error. Hopefully I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Thanks, but shouldn't `BadRowFormat` already know that it is an inner class of `CsvReader` ? It seems verbose to have to pass this information to it.

Comment: I may be wrong but looking at the Exception implementation in Python it will just get the rightmost section of type name based on the code here https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/exceptions.c#L124 and here https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/145bf269df3530176f6ebeab1324890ef7070bf8/Objects/typeobject.c#L475 . While the type does know that it's nested the message will not show it. Maybe it's worth raising a github issue for this.